# ReactJS communicate with ios WKWebView

Tags: javascript, swift, reactjs, wkwebview

I am working on a RWD website that built by ReactJS, and it also used WKWebview to build an app, but I got some problems with ReactJS communicate ios WkWebview
I have a function like below

```
constructor() {
    this.sendLocation = this.sendLocation.bind(this);
}

sendLocation(latitude, longitude) {
    console.log('longitude: ', longitude);
    console.log('latitude: ', latitude);
    this.setState({
      geoLocation: {
        lat: latitude,
        lng: longitude,
      },
    });
 }
```

ios use the same function sendLocation(), but I use safari to debug on app,
I got ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sendLocation
Did anyone encounter this problem before could help me?
Thanks

**Update:**
I use window function to declare sendLocation() to be a global function, and it worked

Comment: your function sendLocation is a class method, not a variable, so it should be accessed like this -  "this.sendLocation"

Comment: @Stundji Thank you for your comment,I try it on ios when webview call "this.sendLocation()", but I got this.sendLocation() is not a function

Comment: React-Native has a Webview component with an option to use WebKit. Can you switch to that ?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview

Comment: @Stundji,Sorry, I can't do that, we have some tech reason,so I can't use react-native,even it's an amazing framework for build an app